# Pull to refresh for simple UIView

Tags: ios, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

Can anybody advice how to implement *pull to refresh* functionality on iOS for a simple `UIView` without `UIScrollView`? 
I've tried to use `UIRefreshControll`, but it should be added either to `UITableView` or `UIScrollView`, but I have just a `UIView`. When I add `UIRefreshControll` to `UIView` my App is crashing.

I do not want to add `UIScrollView` to the existing layout, because my screen is splitted to two section: top part is `UIView` and bottom part is `UITableView`. If I add `UIScrollView` to the top part I'll have 2 `UIScrollView` on the same screen, what I think is not good. But I need  *pull to refresh* for the whole screen, to that user can refresh both top and bottom part of the screen.

I'd appreciate any ideas.

My code example:

```
public override ViewDidLoad()
{
    var refresh = new UIRefreshControl();
    MyView.Add(refresh); // crash here
    //MyView.AddSubview(refresh); // such option also causes crash
}
```

Comment: display your code

Comment: @JigarDarji I've added code example. It is for Xamarin, but I'd appreciate for advises on any language.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in 2 ways :-

(1.) You need to add pan gesture recogniser interactively to UIView and needs to adjust y position of both UIView and UITableview according to pan movement downwards and after some threshold value you have to move UIView and UITableView back to its default position.

**NOTE:-** In this case, you have to add circular loader animation also, same as how it comes in UIRefreshControl. This will also be a part of interactive pan gesture.

(2.) You can add UIView as a section header of UITableView.

Comment: thank you for the advice. the second option actually doesn't feet my needs, because I already have section headers in my table view. I'll try to use the first option.

Comment: Did you find it useful?

Comment: we decided not to invent a bicycle, and decided to put our view of a scroll view, it is not perfect solution, but it is good enough for our needs and needed the least amount of effort